# vba elseif wont run next condition

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have to create a user form and the code wont run the next condition

```
If name = "" Then

   MsgBox ("please enter your name")

    End

ElseIf Cleanbox = False And CavBox = False And RayBox = False And FluBox = False And RootBox = False And OtherBox = False Then


    MsgBox ("Please select a service")


    End
ElseIf Cleanbox = True Then

    total = total + 35

ElseIf CavBox = True Then

    total = total + 150

ElseIf RayBox = True Then

    total = total + 85

ElseIf FluBox = True Then

    total = total + 50

ElseIf RootBox = True Then

    total = total + 225

ElseIf OtherBox = True Then

    total = total + other

End If

totaltxt.Value = total

End Sub
```

At the point where `total = total + x` it wont add the next value.
So if `raybox` is true total will = 85
but if`raybox` is true as well as `flubox`
then total should = 135 but it remains 85.

Comment: Use if raybox is true and fluxboxis true then statement. I guess the elseif condition is executed if the `if` condition is not met. So you have to check for both the condition using And keyword.

Answer (score 2):

you could simply go like follows:

```
If Name = "" Then
    MsgBox ("please enter your name")

ElseIf Not (Cleanbox Or CavBox Or RayBox Or FluBox Or RootBox Or OtherBox) Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a service")

Else
    totaltxt.Value = -(35 * Cleanbox + 150 * CavBox + 85 * RayBox + 50 * FluBox + 225 * RootBox + othervalue * OtherBox)
End If
```

besides, I'd suggest you not to use the `End` statement (google it and you'll see plenty of reasons why) and use proper `If-Then logic` instead to lead to `End Sub`

Comment: @BaraHansen: did you get through it?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is simply wrong. In an `If ... ElseIf ... Else ...` block only the first part with a positive condition will be executed like:

```
If a = 1 Then
  Debug.Print "a is 1"
ElseIf b = 1 Then
  Debug.Print "b is 1"
End If
```

the "b is 1" only is able to pop up if a is not 1. just think of an invisible `[all previous conditions are false] And [this condition]`.

To make your sub workable, either use the way user3598756 showed or something like this:

```
  Dim Total As Long

  If Name = "" Then
    MsgBox ("please enter your name")
  Else
    If Cleanbox Then Total = Total + 35
    If CavBox Then Total = Total + 150
    If RayBox Then Total = Total + 85
    If FluBox Then Total = Total + 50
    If RootBox Then Total = Total + 225
    If OtherBox Then Total = Total + other

    If Total > 0 Then
      totaltxt.Value = Total
    Else
      MsgBox ("Please select a service")
    End If
  End If
```